# Template class implementation has compilation issues

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, derived-class

I am creating an object using static member function of a class. and then calling a function inside.

```
int main(){
  int a = 49;
  auto foo = Foo::createFoo(a);

  foo->study();
}
```

**Implementation**
for this example lets have `study()` display a value.
Structure wise I do have constraints to have the below interface and then the static method returning the object

```
class I_Foo{
public:
  virtual void study(void) = 0;
};

class Foo : public I_Foo{
public:
  static Foo* createFoo(int x_) {
    return new Foo(x_);
  }
  
  void study() override{
    std::cout << "studied: "<< st << std::endl;
  }

protected:
  Foo(int a) : st(a) {}

  int st = 0;
};
```

This above implementation is absolutely working good and as expected *i.e., variable `a` should be displayed as `studied: a`*

Now I want to change the behaviour of this
Lets say for values below 50, the above implementation should remain **"unchanged"** *i.e., variable `a` should be displayed as `studied: a`*
However as the value becomes 50 and above then the output should display `studied: a+100`

```
#include <iostream>

class I_Foo{
public:
  virtual void study(void) = 0;
};

template<int>
class FooImpl;

class Foo : public I_Foo {
public:
  static Foo* createFoo(int x_) {
    
    Foo* foo = nullptr;
    if (x_>=50) {
        foo = new FooImpl<2>(x_);
    }
    else {
        foo = new FooImpl<1>(x_);
    }
    return foo;
  }
};

template<int FT = 1>
class FooImpl : public Foo{
public:

  void study() override{
    std::cout << "studied: "<< st << std::endl;
  }

  FooImpl(int a) : st(a) {}

  int st = 0;
};

template<>
void FooImpl<2>::study() override{
  std::cout << "studied: "<< st + 100 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 56;
  auto foo = Foo::createFoo(a);

  foo->study();
}
```

This obviously doesnot compile as the `Foo` has no clue what `FooImpl` is!

Please suggest how can I make this work. The requirement is to keep the main function untouched but have the new functionality.

**Please note**
Yes, I know this could be solved by if statement, but that is not the point. It has a complex implementation in reality I just tried to present it in a fairly understandable problem to study how these templates could work.

**EDIT 1**
After first editt I seeing the below compliation error
[image: abc]

Comment: Forward declare `FooImpl` before `Foo`?

Comment: How? I tried doing `template<int>\nclass FooImpl;` doesn't work!

Comment: Do not implement `createFoo` function inside the class declaration, just declare it and implement it just before `main`. Also fix casts to cast pointers.

Comment: ... or don't cast at all. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/T3sesaMvv)

Comment: hi @nsilent22, `createFoo` is a must. It had a working implementation like that as shown in the Implementation part. and is one of the critical area of code.

Comment: @RC0993 i do not want you to omit this function, just do not implement it right in the class.

Comment: @RC0993 Did you check my example?

Comment: Yea man I just checked. it works great. WooHoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment: Do not implement `createFoo` function inside the class declaration.

```
#include <iostream>

class I_Foo {
public:
  virtual void study(void) = 0;
};

class Foo : public I_Foo {
public:
  // here just DECLARE the method...
  static Foo *createFoo(int x_);
};

/********/
/* SNIP */
/********/

// ...and IMPLEMENT it there
Foo *Foo::createFoo(int x_) {
    if (x_>=50) { 
      return new FooImpl<2>(x_);
    } else {
      return new FooImpl<1>(x_);
    }
}

int main() {
  int a = 56;
  auto foo = Foo::createFoo(a);

  foo->study();
}
```